# Customize sitemap area icon and label

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I've been able to remove sitemap areas, add and remove subareas from the default sitemap in CRM 2013 but I did not have any success with editing the name or appearance of existing sitemap areas. Is it possible to do something as simple as rename the marketing area and have it display the same icon as the settings area, for instance? When I tried this the area either did not display or included a label "Unknown #", with # being some single digit number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use https://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com/. There is an application in there called SiteMap editor that will let you change the icons, hide areas, and show areas. I recommend you test this out in a sandbox instance first, then use a solution to import it to live.

With that being said, the out of the box sitemap areas can't have their titles and descriptions changed. You can create a new one, then title it whatever you would like however.

Answer (score 0):

Add title in group tag.

< Group Id="sales" Title="Sales">

< Subarea Id="Invoice" Entity"invoice" />

< /Group>